# Does this H-Bridge need any supporting circuitry?

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge

I'm still pretty new to transistor stuff, so excuse the n00b question. I'm looking to use [this](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/ZXMHC6A07N8.pdf) h-bridge to toggle a latching solenoid valve, where I need to toggle it on/off with +/- 6VDC. I've used a SN754410 before, and there the control lines could go straight to my arduino. I assume here I can run the 4 gate lines to 4 separate arduino pins, and control the polarity that way?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the model of the latching solenoid valve?

Comment: something generic off of ebay -> http://www.ebay.com/itm/120886526629

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, no. You should be all set. Some things to look for:

1. Threshold Voltage of the FETs - are 1-3 volts so a 5V control line will be fine. In addition, they are FETs, so you can directly connect. No need for any additional components.
2. Current - the h-bridge can tolerate currents in excess of an amp and your solenoid only needs 220mA - 350mA.
3. Drain-Source voltage - is 60 and the solenoid only operates at 6.
4. Enable lines - unlike the SN754410, the ZXMHC6A07N8 doesn't have them, so you are set there.

Pullup/down resistors at the gates are a good idea to make sure the gates default to a safe voltage when there is no output from the microcontroller.

On the software side, just be careful to avoid shoot-through conditions. That is, when switching the FETs on and off, be sure there can't be a scenario when a P1 and N1 or P2 and N2 are both conducting, shorting the supply.

Comment: I just remember sample circuits showing BJTs being needed to drive P-MOSFETs, hence the question. Thanks!

Comment: There could be something I am overlooking, but my guess is that the threshold voltage was greater than what the microcontroller could provide. Thus, you can use a transistor as a buffer and drive the FET of a gate with a higher voltage. For high power FETs, they have gate driver ICs to do just this. It also could have just been an inverter as well since to turn a pMOSFET "on"(conducting), you apply 0 volts. With an inverter, you could avoid the reverse logic.